# Breadth-first Search: how to get currency exchange?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, numpy, breadth-first-search

I am doing some LeetCode like questions to practice and encountered this question:

```
Given a list of currency pairs and the rates between these two currencies:
 
// USD = 6.4CNY, CNY = 0.13 EUR, EUR = 0.87 GBP, GBP = 89.4 INR
//
 
// Question: Input two currencies, return the rate

// Example: CNY, INR; return 10.1111
 
// Complexity?
```

Wondering if there is any Python 3 way to solve this problem? Looks like a Breadth-first Search problem. Any leads on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment:

I see a solution here:

https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-division/discuss/88275/Python-fast-BFS-solution-with-detailed-explantion

```
class Solution(object):
    
    def calcEquation(self, equations, values, queries):

        graph = {}
        
        def build_graph(equations, values):
            def add_edge(f, t, value):
                if f in graph:
                    graph[f].append((t, value))
                else:
                    graph[f] = [(t, value)]
            
            for vertices, value in zip(equations, values):
                f, t = vertices
                add_edge(f, t, value)
                add_edge(t, f, 1/value)
        
        def find_path(query):
            b, e = query
            
            if b not in graph or e not in graph:
                return -1.0
                
            q = collections.deque([(b, 1.0)])
            visited = set()
            
            while q:
                front, cur_product = q.popleft()
                if front == e:
                    return cur_product
                visited.add(front)
                for neighbor, value in graph[front]:
                    if neighbor not in visited:
                        q.append((neighbor, cur_product*value))
            
            return -1.0
        
        build_graph(equations, values)
        
        return [find_path(q) for q in queries]
    
s=Solution()
```

Wonder how can I test this function?

```
s.calcEquation('USD/CNY=?, CNY/EUR = ?, EUR/GBP = ?, GBP/INR = ?', '6.4, 0.13, 0.87, 89.4','CNY/INR=?')
```

give me the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/coderpad/solution.py", line 45, in <module>
    s.calcEquation('USD/CNY=?, CNY/EUR = ?, EUR/GBP = ?, GBP/INR = ?', '6.4, 0.13, 0.87, 89.4','CNY/INR=?')
  File "/home/coderpad/solution.py", line 39, in calcEquation
    build_graph(equations, values)
  File "/home/coderpad/solution.py", line 15, in build_graph
    f, t = vertices
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: Would a bfs solution in Java be of any help to you ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this'd work, however you don't need the `values` variable here, because they are already in the `equations`.

Here, we are using a `re.findall()` to get those three desired strings (currencies and the ratio), and then we'd loop through:

```
import collections
import re


class Solution:
    def calcEquation(self, equations, values, queries):
        memo = collections.defaultdict(dict)
        for equation in equations:
            num, val, den = re.findall(
                r'^\s*([A-Z]{3})\s*=\s*([0-9.]+)\s*([A-Z]{3})\s*$', equation)[0]

            val = float(val)
            memo[num][num] = memo[den][den] = 1.
            memo[num][den] = val
            memo[den][num] = 1 / val

        for key in memo:
            for val in memo[key]:
                for i in memo[key]:
                    memo[val][i] = memo[val][key] * memo[key][i]

        return [memo[num].get(den, -1.) for num, den in queries]


equations = ['USD = 6.4CNY', 'CNY = 0.13 EUR', 'EUR = 0.87 GBP', 'GBP = 89.4 INR']
values = [6.4, 0.13, 0.87, 89.4]
queries = [["USD", "CNY"], ["CNY", "EUR"], ["EUR", "GBP"], ["GBP", "INR"]]

print(Solution().calcEquation(equations, queries))
```

Technically, you don't have to manually add the `values`, if you don't want to. We can safely remove the `values` variable:

```
import collections
import re


class Solution:
    def calcEquation(self, equations, queries):
        memo = collections.defaultdict(dict)
        for equation in equations:
            num, val, den = re.findall(
                r'^\s*([A-Z]{3})\s*=\s*([0-9.]+)\s*([A-Z]{3})\s*$', equation)[0]

            val = float(val)
            memo[num][num] = memo[den][den] = 1.
            memo[num][den] = val
            memo[den][num] = 1 / val

        for key in memo:
            for val in memo[key]:
                for i in memo[key]:
                    memo[val][i] = memo[val][key] * memo[key][i]

        return [memo[num].get(den, -1.) for num, den in queries]


equations = ['USD = 6.4CNY', 'CNY = 0.13 EUR', 'EUR = 0.87 GBP', 'GBP = 89.4 INR']
queries = [["USD", "CNY"], ["CNY", "EUR"], ["EUR", "GBP"], ["GBP", "INR"]]

print(Solution().calcEquation(equations, queries))
```

#### Outputs

```
[6.399999999999987, 0.12999999999999973, 0.8699999999999983, 89.39999999999993]
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vbnGJa/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/vbnGJa/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---